# Understanding getaddrinfo function in C

Tags: c, linux, network-programming, getaddrinfo

I'm new to C and socket programming, just a question on `getaddrinfo` function. The function prototype of `getaddrinfo` is:

```
int getaddrinfo(const char *host, const char *service, const struct addrinfo *hints, struct addrinfo **result);
```

and `getaddrinfo` returns a result that points to a linked list of addrinfo structures, each of which points to a socket address structure that corresponds to host and service.
[image]

Below is my questions:

Q1-Why it needs to return a result that points to a **linked list** of `addrinfo` structures? I mean that given a host and service, these is only one unique socket address, how could it be more than one valid socket address so that a linked list is needed?

Q2-the last parameter is `struct addrinfo **result`, why it is a pointer to a pointer? Why it is not `struct addrinfo *result`, and then `getaddrinfo` creates sth internally and let `result`(`struct addrinfo *`) point to it?
someone says it is due to `getaddrinfo` call `malloc` internally, but I can also code like this

```
int main() 
{
   char *ptr_main;
   test(ptr_main);
   free(ptr_main);
}

void test(char * ptr)
{ 
    ptr = malloc(10); 
}
```

so the parameter to the function is `char *ptr`, not `char **ptr`.

Comment: "these is only one unique socket address" Not correct. For one, a host *name* may have many different *addresses* associated with it. "and let result(struct addrinfo *) point to it" If your function wants to change something, it needs to accept a pointer to that something as a parameter. `result` is a pointer so it needs a pointer to a pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`getaddrinfo()` returns a list of address because an hostname can have more than an address. Think for example to those high traffic sites that need to distribute visitors through different IPs.

Since [`getaddrinfo()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getaddrinfo)

> **combines the functionality provided by the gethostbyname(3)** and getservbyname(3) functions into a single interface, but unlike the latter functions, getaddrinfo() is reentrant and allows programs to eliminate IPv4-versus-IPv6 dependencies

it might trigger a DNS session to resolve an host name. In case of those aforementioned high traffic sites the same hostname will correspond to a list of actual addresses.

---

You also ask:

> `struct addrinfo **result`, why is it a pointer to a pointer?

In C a pointer to something is passing as a parameter of a function when it has to modify it. So, for example, in case you need to modify an integer, you pass `int *`. This particular kind of *modification* is very common in C when you want to return something through a parameter; in our previous example we can return an extra integer by accessing the pointer passed as a parameter.

But what if a function wants to allocate something? It will result, internally in a `type * var = malloc()`, meaning that a pointer to `type` would be returned. And in order to return it as a parameter we need to pass a `type **` parameter.

Is it clear the logic? Given a `type`, if you wat to return it as a parameter you have to define it as a pointer to `type`.

In conclusion, in our case the function `getaddrinfo` needs to modify a variable which type is `struct addrinfo *`, so `struct addrinfo **` is the parameter type.

Just to mention the meaning of this parameter:

> The getaddrinfo() function **allocates** and initializes a linked list of addrinfo structures, one for each network address that matches node and service, subject to any restrictions imposed by hints, and returns a pointer to the start of the list in res. The items in the linked list are linked by the ai_next field.

As you can see we actually have an allocation inside the function. So this memory will need to be eventually freed:

> The freeaddrinfo() function frees the memory that was allocated for the dynamically allocated linked list res.

---

### Why not just a `type *` parameter?

Your code example results in undefined behavior, and when I run it it caused a program crash.

**Why?** Is I wrote above, in C parameters are passed **by value**. It means that in case of a `func(int c)` function, called in this way

```
int b = 1234;

funct(b);
```

the parameter `c` internally used by the function will be a *copy* of `b`, and any change on it won't survive outside the function.

The same happens in case of `func(char *        ptr)` (please note the huge spacing, to underline how the type is `char *` and the variable is `ptr`): any change on `ptr` won't survive outside the function. **You'll be able to change the memory it points, and these changes will be available after the function returns, but the variable passed as a parameter will be the same it was before the call to `func()`.

And what was the value of `ptr_main`, in your example, before `test` was called? We don't know, as the variable is uninitialized. So, the behavior is undefined.

If you still have doubts, here it is a program that demonstrates that the newly allocated address obtained by value cannot be accessed from outside `the function`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void test(char * ptr)
{ 
    ptr = malloc(10); 

    printf("test:\t%p\n", ptr);
}

int main() 
{
    char *ptr_main = (char *) 0x7777;

    printf("main-1:\t%p\n", ptr_main);
    test(ptr_main);
    printf("main-2:\t%p\n", ptr_main);
}
```

**Output:**

```
main-1: 0000000000007777
test:   0000000000A96D60
main-2: 0000000000007777
```

Even after the function call the value of `ptr_main` is the same it after I initialized it (`0x7777`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so for question 2, I can also do like `int test(char * ptr){ ptr = malloc(10); }`, so the parameter doesn't need to be s `char **ptr`

Comment: @amjad Uhm... no. I probably wasn't clear enough and I'll have to reword. Parameters are passed by value, so ptr won't be usable outside your function (you won't be able to free it). So if you need to return a pointer, you need a duble pointer parameter.

Comment: I added some additional code in my post to depicit it, I can still free the resource allocated by `malloc`, it is true there will be two pointers point to the same resource,but calling free() on one of them can free the resource.

Comment: @amjad sorry for the late update bt I was at work. I updated my answer showing why your previous assertion is wrong. I'm not sure about the reason why you didn't experience a crash (as I did). Maybe it silently happen after the process exit, or maybe your compiler omitted the free because it occurred just before process ending (when the OS would release the memory anyway).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I see :)